# Jquery animate script not working within table-cell layout

Tags: css, responsive-design, jquery-animate, css-tables

I found this jQuery animate script -> http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/dsHyf/ which works perfectly fine for me when I try it standalone. But as soon as I want to include it into my responsive layout using display: table-cell and %-widths everything looks out of place.

I want the .full to fill out 100% of the width and height of the .cell.
Is it possible to adjust this to fluid layouts instead of fixed widths? I have been trying for hours... Or is there a better solution?

I simply want to exchange a first "tile" showing a headline with a second "tile" showing a text/list with a smooth animate effect.

Plus I want to use this script multiple times on the same pages. What can I do?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <h1>Text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="full" id="div1"></div>
            <div class="full" id="div2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="full" id="div1"></div>
            <div class="full" id="div2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
.full{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#div1{
    background:#FF0000;
    left:0px;
}
#div2{
    display:none;
    background:#FFFF00;
}

.container{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.cell{
    display: table-cell;
 }

div.container div:nth-child(1){
   width: auto;
}

div.container div:nth-child(2), div.container div:nth-child(3){
   width: 40%
}
```

JS:

```
$('#div2').css('left',-$('#wrapper').width()).show();

$('#div1').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({'left':$('#wrapper').width()});
    $('#div2').animate({'left':0});
});

$('#div2').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({'left':-$('#wrapper').width()});
    $('#div1').animate({'left':0});
});
```